# Javascript to restrict to add the same item more than once to the second listbox

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict to add the same item more than once to the second listbox, i think i am very close to it . please help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyFile() {
        var firstListBox = document.getElementById('<%= lstFirstBox.ClientID %>');
        var secondListBox = document.getElementById('<%= lstTarget.ClientID %>');
        for (var i = 0; i < firstListBox.options.length; i++) {
            if (firstListBox.options[i].selected) {
                for (var j = 0; j < secondListBox.options.length; j++) {
                    if (firstListBox.options[i].selected == secondListBox.options[j]) {
                        alert("Multiple selection will not allow");
                    }
                    else {
                        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                        newOption.text = firstListBox.options[i].text;
                        newOption.value = firstListBox.options[i].value;
                        secondListBox.options[secondListBox.options.length] = newOption;
                        firstListBox.options[i].selected = false;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Any errors?

Comment: code doesnot copy the item from first listbox to another..

Comment: have you tried using `appendChild` on this line? `secondListBox.options[secondListBox.options.length] = newOption;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote you an example. Following html page has two selects and one button. If you select an option in the first select and press the button, the option will be copied to the second select, unless it's already there. In the last case, it will alert a message. to try it, copy paste it in a file (for example "test.htm") and open it in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function tryToCopy() {
                var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
                var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
                var optionToBeCopied = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex];
                var contains = false;
                for(var i = 0, ceiling = select2.options.length; i < ceiling; i++) {
                    if(select2.options[i].value == optionToBeCopied.value) {
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(contains) {
                        alert("duplicate options are not allowed.");
                } else {
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    select2.appendChild(option);
                    option.value = optionToBeCopied.value;
                    option.text = optionToBeCopied.text;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="select1">
            <option value="" selected="true"></option>
            <option value="a">a</option>
            <option value="b">b</option>
        </select>
        <select id="select2">
        </select>
        <input type="button" value="tryToCopy" onclick="tryToCopy()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the selected item is not copying to next listbox

Comment: Thank you very much tom let me try this